# "left" or "the left" of the image?

Tags: grammar

This image shows 5 balls horizontally.

[image]

When I refer to American Football, should I say

> **left** of the image

or

> **the left** of the image

I know the basic rules about [the usage of A/an and the](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/a-an-and-the)

Could someone please give a hint about this kind of particular case? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The football is on "the left" side of the image.  A better way to say this would be "the leftmost item in the image".  This means whatever item (in this case ball) is the furthest (most far) to the left.